# Pathfinding to escaping target (chase or pursuit pathfinding)

Tags: search, real-time, path-finding, a-star

I'm struggling to implement a good chaser. I have a hockey player who needs to chase a puck. I can predict both next player and puck positions. I was trying to use steering behaviors but failed to find a good predictor for situations when puck is close (imagine for example the puck heads almost towards the player with a high speed. The player makes just a little angle turns when the puck is somewhat away. However when the puck comes closer and it just misses the player, the last two-three ticks the player needs to turn much bigger angles to still be looking at the puck. When there's a limit to the turning angle, the puck escapes and the player can't do anything. If it started to turn earlie, it would be just fine, but when I predict more steps, the player tends to start turning for a puck position far behind him...). Then I was going to use a* search. Works great while the puck is ahead and the puck speed is lower then that of the player. However when the puck speed is bigger, it becomes an escaping target. So every time a* expands a new state, it tends to look back and find that on the previous states the puck was closer to the player (the puck escapes!), so it prefers the previous states and becomes bfs.
So I guess there's a well-known solution to this, but I fail to google anything on that, so maybe community will help me. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: so basically I reinvented the wheel I guess. What I'm doing now is I'm iterating through the puck positions. When I hit the first position that is reachable with the same number of ticks, I declare victory. This is VERY resource expensive, but I couldn't come up with anything better.

Comment: If you're looking for something more advanced than A\*/steering, you could look into the "Moving Target" algorithms listed [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/11866/8532)

Comment: I can't get my head around that 'constant recalculation'. It looks to me like following a point too far behind the target. How is that different from just heading to where the target is NOW? Instead, I want to find a method of identifying the interception path - i.e. heading to a direction where the target will be in just the right time when I will be there. Not earlier not later. To be able to intercept it.

Answer (score 1):

The part about the behavior is pretty hard to understand at the moment but about the `A*` problem I think that your problem is that since your agent (the player) is operating in a dynamic environment you have to re-compute the heuristic every expansion step because of course, the `h` values for the states in the fronteer are now obsolete since the puck is moving. Am I any close to having understood what your problem is?

Curiosity, what kind of heuristic are you using?

Comment: I think you are spot on. Heuristic is whatever - most of the time I'm trying either just air distance or air distance plus direction difference. So basically I should update the weight whenever I pop anything from the fringe? So I would pop the state, check heuristic, if it was updated, I'd put this state back to fringe with the new weight instead of expanding it?

Comment: If you are performing real time A* you have to do it every time before you move in a state that is in the fringe (your actual state). And only then choose the cheapest `g + h`.
Btw A* in this domain is non trivial and there are better solutions imho